# Run X applications as another user under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, gksudo

Visiting the old topic of *running X applications as another user under Linux*, as the solution had always been "*to use `gksu`*" to me, but today, when I need it and tried it, it doesn't work.

Following [What Is gksu And Why Would You Use It](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-gksu-2189402), I tried,

```
gksu -u otherusername xterm
```

After passing the dialog that asks for the password, I got:

```
$ gksu -u otherusername xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :2
```

I.e., it doesn't work for me. So,

How to run X applications as another user under Linux? Thx.

PS, this is Ubuntu 17.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty
```

Comment: What kind of X authorization does your distribution use (read up on `xauth`)? You must authorize the "other use" to use the display of the "first user".

Comment: Yes I use `xauth`, and no, I don't know how to authorize the "other use" to use the display of the "first user", please help @dirkt, that must be the missing piece to the answer. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 17, right? **Are you sure you are actually running Xorg, and not *Wayland*?** (i.e. does `ps auxfww` actually shows a program called `X` running?)

If you are running Wayland-- which you would be by default: accessing the display from root user [is not allowed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961975#961975) due to a security *feature* (cough)(cough). They said you could work around by running this command *before* attempting to run gksu:

```
xhost si:localuser:root
```

Another way is to just start your Ubuntu system with conventional Xorg display system; [you can set this at login, I think](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

I never used Ubuntu 17 though, and definitely not a Wayland user. This is probably one of the reasons that [Ubuntu 18/LTS will go back to use classic Xorg by default](https://news.slashdot.org/story/18/01/26/1437212/ubuntu-1804-lts-will-default-to-the-xorg-stack-not-wayland).

**Important note:** If *otherusername* of yours **is not *root***, no matter that you're using Wayland or classic Xorg, you need to run following command before running your program via gksu:

```
xhost si:localuser:otherusername
```

**UPDATE:**

The above solution is not working for Ubuntu 17.04 Xorg out of the box:

```
$ xhost si:localuser:root
localuser:root being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0xe
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
```

It [looks like](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2006-November/019887.html) that Ubuntu Xorg *"server is not built with SECURE_RPC support, so attempting to add a FamilyNetname (0xfe) host fails."*

So no out of the box solution for Ubuntu yet (but this remains as *the* answer until a working one exist).

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04, not Ubuntu 17.10, and yes it is definitely Xorg. Never knew `xhost` can be used that way -- only know the `xhost +`, which is deemed to be unsafe. Thanks for the answer xwindows! Welcome aboard, with my +25, :-)

Comment: I finally get a chance to test it, but it is not working *for me*. I took the liberty to update your answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `DISPLAY` environment variable; it looks like the new user is trying to use display `:2`, which probably doesn't have an X server attached.

You can try something like: `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`, which should tell otherusername's X application to use the current user's X server. (I'm pretty sure this is a hack, because this variable should be configured correctly without having to set it, some more details [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Xwindows/exporting_display.shtml#Exporting_display_on_the_client).)

Comment: My DISPLAY ***is*** `DISPLAY=':2'`, believe it or not but I'm not going to explain my complicated setup, so in short, `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` won't cut it, as `DISPLAY=':2'` is working fine for all my own X apps. But thanks for helping though.

Answer (score -1):

1. assign the password to this `otheruser`. on behalf of the superuser:

   `passwd otheruser`
2. If the sudo program is installed, add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`, for example:

   `user ALL = (otheruser) ALL`

this will allow the `user` to execute any programs / commands on behalf of the user `otheruser`:

```
`$ sudo -u otheruser xterm`
```

The user's `user` password will be requested.

can be done without a password request by adding the `NOPASSWD` directive: to the above line:

`user ALL = (otheruser) NOPASSWD: ALL`

original - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473607/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Many help additional flags `-c` or `-p`

Comment: The problem is X authorization ("can't open display"), which your answer doesn't address at all ...